# Avoid having to duplicate code in sibling classes

Tags: java

Beginner question - how do I avoid repeating code in sibling classes, where each has its own different version of the same field?
See example below: can I somehow move the getName() method (as well as far more complex methods) to the parent class?

```
public abstract class Car {
    public abstract String getName();
}

public class PassengerCar extends Car {
   private String name = "Passenger Car";

   @Override
   public String getName() { return name; }
}

public class CoalCar extends Car {
   private String name = "Coal Car";

   @Override
   public String getName() { return name; }
}
```

Comment: Tried anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, for example: create a constructor in the parent class which takes a name, and specify that name in the constructor of the child classes:

```
abstract class Car {

    private String name;

    public Car(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }

}

class PassengerCar extends Car {

    public PassengerCar() {
        super("Passenger Car");
    }

}

class CoalCar extends Car {

    public CoalCar() {
        super("Coal Car");
    }

}
```

Which then can be used like this:

```
Car passenger = new PassengerCar();
System.out.println(passenger.getName());
```

This prints out:

```
Passenger Car
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mark's answer is the solution, but let me add a bit of background to it.

Simple rule of thumb: if you want something that all subclasses have in common, place it into the parent class.

What do you have?

- a field called `name` used by all subclasses (it doesn't matter that the values are different, see below),
- a getter called `getName()` used by all subclasses,
- an initial value `"Passenger Car"` for all `PassengerCar` instances,
- an initial value `"Coal Car"` for all `CoalCar` instances.

So, the `name` field and the `getName()` method go into `Car`, and the different initial values for that field go into the constructors of `PassengerCar` and `CoalCar`.